# Why does my material look blotchy on this mesh?

Tags: unity, 3d, mesh, materials

This is a generative mesh - wireframe looks like this
[image]

Here's the material
[image]

But the shaded object looks like a tie dye tshirt
[image]

I've no idea what settings are causing it to look like this. These are the settings of the mesh renderer
[image]

Comment: How did you set up the UV map for that mesh? If you didn't, then that's what you need to do.

Comment: There isn't one - that sounds like a good lead, thanks

Comment: I'd also be curious how you've generated the mesh normals. We're seeing very strange interpolation artifacts between the vertices, which can happen if your normals are seriously warped around compared to the surface.

Comment: Quick correction: your second image shows a *texture* not a *material*. Materials can use textures, but the two are separate things.

Answer (score 1):

It appears like you generated the mesh vertices, but did not generate any texture coordinates (aka uv map) for them. Texture coordinates are important, because they tell the renderer which part of the texture should be visible on which polygon of your 3d mesh.

So when you generate a mesh using the [Mesh](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.html) class, make sure that you don't just fill the `.vertices` array but also the `.uv` array with one `Vector2` for each `Vector3` in your vertices array.

Comment: I've no clue how to do this - is it as simple as `mesh.SetUVs(0, vertices)` or do I need to do a more complex process?

I also ran `mesh.RecalculateNormals()` to get the normals, but this doesn't seem to have made any difference to the rendering.

Comment: @Tom every Every `Vector3` in your vertices array needs a corresponding `Vector2` in your uv array. These Vector2's are pixel-coordinates on your texture and are used to determine which part of the texture is visible on which polygon. So the values depend on how exactly you want to apply your texture. There is no simple one-line shortcut for this. You will have to think about this for a bit.